# Multer appears to receive an empty object when uploading form data and not uploading file

Tags: multer

I'm attempting to upload a file from a local node js build to a server.
The return value is an empty object {}

In my client:

```
const file = await fs.readFileSync(`${desktopDir}/ai2html-output/home-pro-Artboard_1.jpg`);
const title = "Test";

const form = new FormData();

form.append("title", title);
form.append("file", file);
```

I then hit fetch using multi part and the boundary added.

```
const response = await fetch('https://example.com/uploads/1234', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`,
      },
  body: form });
const responseData = await response.json();

console.log(responseData);
```

console.log responseData is = {}

My code in the server is:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/html/' });

router.post('/uploads/:id', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  const title = req.body;
  res.send(title);
  res.json({ msg: `file ${title} uploaded successfully!` });
});
```

As you can see I'm responding with req.body so I can see what is received.  This comes back as the empty object {}

```
Before we hit fetch I console.log form which is:
dataSize: 0
maxDataSize: 2097152
pauseStreams: true
readable: true
writable: false
_boundary: "--------------------------527262518687012104513615"
_currentStream: null
_insideLoop: false
_overheadLength: 247
_pendingNext: false
_released: false
_streams: Array(6)
0: "----------------------------527262518687012104513615
↵Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
↵
↵"
1: "Test"
2: ƒ ()
3: "----------------------------527262518687012104513615
↵Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
↵Content-Type: application/octet-stream
↵
↵"
4: Buffer(42595) […]
5: ƒ ()
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
_valueLength: 42599
```

My request header returned from the server is:

```
:method: POST
:path: /uploads/1234
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 17
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------135231531961009802519979
origin: file://
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

In my express server I also have BodyParser:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

I'm not sure if that's affecting it.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, thank you!